# Отсчёт времени в базе данных

Tags: sql, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite

У меня есть некая мини игра в которой раз в день можно получить бонус. При реализации этой игры я задумался как мне хранить оставшейся время до бонуса для каждого пользователя в базе данных. Можно конечна сделать таймер на python по типу `time.sleep(30)` а дальше изменение времени (оставшегося) в БД на более новую но что то мне подсказывает что это костыль.

Как сделать это правильно или как делали это вы?

Answer (score 1):

Для определения некого события связанного с временем ожидания мы применяем следующий подход:

В бд добавляется дата, от которой считается временной интервал относительно текущей даты проверки наступления события. В вашем случае это дата и время последнего начисления бонуса.

Далее с некой дискретностью запускаем крон проверки. Дискретность этого крона подбирается по чистоте возникновения проверяемого события(в вашем случае можно поставить интервал проверки раз в час, так как мы говорим о необходимости настоять балы раз в сутки).

В рамках проверки мы выбираем все записи, дата последнего начисления бонусов больше на одни сутки, начисляем бонусы этим пользователям, и ставим дату последнего начисления бонусов текущей. Через час этот же крон выберет новую партию играков.

Comment: Если по наступлению события ничего не надо менять в проверяемой сущности тут несколько усложняется проверка от повторов. Например просто отправлять письмо юзеру, который сутки назад был зарегестрирован, но не сделал каких то ожидаемых действий. В этом случае нам пришлось использовать еще время предыдущего вызова крона, чтобы анализировать только свежие даты + создать таблицу с хешами уже сработанных событий(само собой с очисткой), чтобы не обрабатывать повторно. Но в итоге получился универсальный механизм...